# How to define unindexed Datastore properties in Golang?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

Can I define unindexed Datastore properties using Golang on app engine?

Answer (score 2):

Sure, just add "noindex" to struct field tag: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/indexes#Go_Unindexed_properties

Answer (score 0):

You can control how Datastore handles struct fields using struct tags. To avoid indexing a field, do the following:

`` type Person struct {
        Age  int `datastore:",noindex"`
} ``

See [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/indexes#Go_Unindexed_properties) for more information.